# How to select by dbid in viewer when several models are loaded?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I load several models in my scene. I would like to:

1. Fit to view from dbId -> this can be done with viewer.fitToView(objectIds,model)
2. Select an element from dbid on a particular model. But viewer.select(dbids,selectionType) does not offer possibility to select the model.

How can we make a selection on a dbid, on specific model, when several models are loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.js) of Forge Viewer v6, the `select` method is defined as

```
Viewer3D.prototype.select = function (dbids, model) { ... }
```

So the second parameter should actually be the model, not a selection type.

Comment: Thanks for answer, then https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#select-dbids-selectiontype is outdated.

Comment: You're right @Fabien, I'll let the team know. Thanks!